# Merge two flat associative arrays and sum values on matching keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge, sum, grouping

I have two associative arrays and they are very similar to each other (But not the same) they are both separate arrays and I want to merge them together while maintaining both the arrays this can be done by:

- Making sure the values ADD if the keys already exist (I.e both the arrays contain the key 'dragon' and maybe the value is '30' on the first array and '26' on the second i want it to give me '56'
- If these keys don't exist in the first array, just merge it normally.

I've tried using `$tagItems = array_count_values($tagItems, $tagItems2);` but this just gives me `null` when i try to json encode and echo it out.

I've also tried using `$tagItems = array_merge($tagItems, $tagItems2);` this **adds** the new keys but doesn't merge the duplicate keys values (just keeps merged array values).

The arrays in JSON format look something like this, one array is called $tagItems, the other is called $tagItems2

```
{
   "game1": 22,
   "game2": 20,
   "game3": 16,
}
{
   "game1": 22,
   "game2": 20,
   "game3": 16,
   "game4": 12,
}
```

What will allow me to do this?

Comment: your going to have to loop though them

Comment: i think you need to extract the values then sum them, then regroup it again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At its shortest form where you want to merge `$b` into `$a`:

```
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
    $a[$key] += $value;
}
```

[Example](https://eval.in/652147)

However, it's best that you check if the array key exists before you write to it:

```
if (!array_key_exists($key, $a)) {
    $a[$key] = 0;
}
$a[$key] += $value;
```

Comment: @nogad, i was writing my answer like this `foreach(){if(key_exists(){$tagItems[$ti2]=$val})}` with variables of course, so what makes my longer better than his shorter???

Comment: @RobbieAverill, i think the OP wants to add the new vals as well as summing the old vals too, so your first works perfectly

Comment: @xYuri the second half of the answer works the same way, just without undefined index errors

Answer (score 1):

This method uses mapping and allows either array to have keys not present in the other array.

```php
$merged = array_fill_keys(array_keys($a + $b), 0);
$sums = array_map(
    function($aVal, $bVal) { return $aVal + $bVal; },
    array_merge($merged, $a),
    array_merge($merged, $b)
);
$merged = array_combine(array_keys($merged), $sums);
```